# Display the names of checkboxes from an array

Tags: php, html, laravel, checkbox

I'm attempting to display the names of my checkboxes with the foreach statement below, but all I'm getting is "on" for each one checked. I've got the code for one of the checkboxes and was wondering if there is anything I can change in it to make this work.

```
if(!empty($_POST['OUSdrop'])){
    foreach($_POST['OUSdrop'] as $check){
        echo $check;
    }
}


<label class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="UKSen">
    <input type="checkbox" id="UKSen" name="OUSdrop[]" class="mdl-checkbox__input">
    <span class="mdl-checkbox__label" value="UK">United Kingdom</span>
</label>
```

Comment: You have set the value of checkbox in `span` tag. Move it to the `input` tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why don't change it as

```
<input type="checkbox" id="UKSen" name="OUSdrop[UK]" class="mdl-
checkbox__input">
```

so that you know which one you want to set?

And also change the loop

```
foreach($_POST['OUSdrop'] as $check => $value){
        echo $check.':'.$value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if(!empty($_POST['OUSdrop'])){

    foreach($_POST['OUSdrop'] as $check => $value){
        echo $check;

    }
}
```

**HTML CODE**

```
<label class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="UKSen">
        <input type="checkbox" id="UKSen" name="OUSdrop[HERE]" class="mdl-checkbox__input">
        <span class="mdl-checkbox__label" value="UK">United Kingdom</span>
</label>
```

`$check` will contain the key ans `$value` the value.

Comment: All I got from that was 012 instead of ononon, and the checkboxes I selected weren't in those positions in the array

Comment: it's because your `OUSdrop[]` is a PHP array that contains indexes of any value stored in it.

Comment: Ended up having to access the $value option after changing the checkbox thanks to your update and that worked!

Answer (score 0):

You have set the value in `span` tag which should be in `input`

When value is not defined most browsers will default to `value="on"` which means that it's 'on' (checked)

```
if (! empty($_POST['OUSdrop'])) {
    foreach($_POST['OUSdrop'] as $check) {
        echo $check;
    }
}


<label class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="UKSen">
    <input type="checkbox" 
           id="UKSen" 
           name="OUSdrop[]" 
           class="mdl-checkbox__input"  
           value="UK">
    <span class="mdl-checkbox__label">United Kingdom</span>
</label>
```